# Background worker not setting `e.result`

Tags: .net, vb.net, backgroundworker

**Overview:**
I have several background workers used to import data into an access database and then carry out some calculations. I pass a `hashtable` of arguments between the background workers using `e.Argument` and `e.Result`. This hashtable contains data about the files that are to be imported.

**Problem:**
On one of my background workers (about fourth in the process), I can't set `e.result`, instead it stays as `nothing`, which then causes an error in the worker completed subroutine. As far as I can tell this is a duplicate of all of my code for my other workers so there is no reason why this one won't set.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub bwConditionCalc_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwConditionCalc.DoWork
    Dim Dates As New List(Of Date)
    Dim Arguments As Hashtable
    Arguments = e.Argument

'Worker Content-----------

    Arguments("VariablesCalculated") = VariablesCalculated
    LabelString = "Tasks Complete..."
    e.Result = Arguments
End Sub

Private Sub bwConditionCalc_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwConditionCalc.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim Arguments As New Hashtable
    Arguments = e.Result
    ' Check if missed calc Params can now be calculated/scaled
'The Error occurs here---------------------       
    If Not Arguments("VariablesCalculated") = 0 Then      
        Arguments("SchedCalculateData") = True
        Arguments("SchedConditionalCalc") = True
    End If
    prgFieldMaster.Value = 0
    lblStatus.Text = LabelString
    RunWorkSchedule(Arguments)
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
The `DeepCopy` routine returns a hashtable, and was put there as an attempted fix. I still get the same Error without `Deep Copy` which I will remove from the quoted code to now.

**EDIT - `e.error` handle**
    Private Sub bwConditionCalc_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwConditionCalc.RunWorkerCompleted

```
    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
    End If
    Dim Arguments As New Hashtable
    Arguments = e.Result
    ' Check if missed calc Params can now be calculated/scaled
    If Not Arguments("VariablesCalculated") = 0 Then
        Arguments("SchedCalculateData") = True
        Arguments("SchedConditionalCalc") = True
    End If
    prgFieldMaster.Value = 0
    lblStatus.Text = LabelString
    RunWorkSchedule(Arguments)
End Sub
```

**EDIT - Worker Schedule**

The sub below is called by a starter subroutine that creates the original Arguments Hashtable. After each worker completes it then calls this sub again in the worker completed rountine.
The cycle before the routine causing this called, I am calling `Importchecker`, `ImportData`, `CalculateData` then `ConditionalCalc`.

```
    Public Sub RunWorkSchedule(ByVal Arguments As Hashtable)
    Me.Refresh()
    'Do nothing if worker is busy
    If bwCalcParam.IsBusy = True Or bwScaleData.IsBusy = True Or bwImportWriter.IsBusy = True Or bwColumnAdder.IsBusy = True Or bwConditionCalc.IsBusy = True Or bwDeleteParameterbyUpload.IsBusy Or bwDeletebyParameterOrCondition.IsBusy Or bwEventCalc.IsBusy Or bwImportChecker.IsBusy Or bwAddRawTables.IsBusy Then Exit Sub
    DataSchedRunning = True
    'Scheduled tasks:

    If Arguments("SchedUploadDelete") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedUploadDelete") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Deleting Data by Upload"
        bwDeleteParameterbyUpload.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedDeletebyParameterOrCondition") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedDeletebyParameterOrCondition") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Deleting Data by Parameter Or Condtion"
        bwDeletebyParameterOrCondition.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedAddRawTables") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedAddRawTables") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Adding raw data tables to the Database..."
        bwAddRawTables.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedColumnAdder") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedColumnAdder") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Adding Columns to the Database..."
        bwColumnAdder.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedImportChecker") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedImportChecker") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to check Import Files..."
        bwImportChecker.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedImportData") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedImportData") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to Import data..."
        bwImportWriter.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedCalculateData") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedCalculateData") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to Calculate data..."
        bwCalcParam.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedConditionalCalc") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedConditionalCalc") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to Calculate Conditional Data..."
        bwConditionCalc.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Arguments("SchedScaleData") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedScaleData") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to Scale Data..."
        bwScaleData.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Arguments("SchedEventCalc") = True Then
        Arguments("SchedEventCalc") = False
        lblStatus.Text = "Preparing to Calculate Events"
        bwEventCalc.RunWorkerAsync(Arguments)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Finish:
    If SchedNewArgument = True Then
        timNextTask.Enabled = True
    End If
    lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Complete"
    StatusStrip1.Refresh()
    DataSchedRunning = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You are forgetting to check e.Error first.  That's a hard requirement, there is no other way to know that the DoWork() event handler terminated early with an exception.  Well, other than the crash you'll get from using a result that's Nothing.  Debug that with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have turned on throw for CLR exceptions, and I still get nothing thrown. I have also added a check of e.error from the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) also see above, but it is also `nothing`. Do I need to change my code within the worker.dowork routine? Many Thanks

Comment: "I pass a hashtable of arguments between the background workers using e.Argument and e.Result."  So you're chaining these together?  Can you show how you're doing this?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, please see above

Comment: Ugh...what a mess.  Personally I'd use just **ONE** BackgroundWorker() and utilize its ReportProgress() method instead of RunWorkerCompleted() and "chaining" it together.  You can still break the code out into different methods to keep it neat.  Then you just have one "main" sequence in the DoWork() handler that calls each step in turn and ReportProgress() afterwards.  It would be soooo much easier to follow the logic and flow of the process.  I also might make it easier to spot where the problem is...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I do use ReportProgress() for a progress bar/ status label. I was unable to figure out how to do this from a method called from within a BackgroundWorker(), but I have some more ideas now. Because of this and a few other issues I was unable to have just one worker for the whole process. I see where you are coming from and I will take your advise on board. However I don't believe that the logic or flow of this process is particularly unclear...

Answer (score 2):

The only way `e.Result` could get set to `Nothing` in this code is `DeepCopy` is returning `Nothing`. It's not an issue with `e.Result`. Debug the `DeepCopy` method with the arguments passed in and you'll find the problem.

Comment: Please see the Edit I have just added above. DeepCopy doesn't change the hashtable and was an attempt at a post error fix. I still get the same error without it.

Comment: @Pezzzz, then that means there is an exception being thrown in the `DoWork` somewhere else. My guess, `e.Argument` is `null` so when you try and access `Arguments` on the next line you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: e.Arguments is not null, I have checked in run time. I guess I need check the rest of the code.